# Powershell use values of one array as headings for another array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have two arrays in Powershell:

```
$headings = ['h1', 'h2']
$values = [3, 4]
```

It is guaranteed that both arrays have the same length. How can I create an array where the values of `$headings` become the headings of the `$values` array?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$result['h2'] #should return 4
```

**Update:**
The arrays `$headings` and `$values` are of type `System.Array`.

Comment: what you need is a [HASHTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6).. I will drop an answer

Comment: thanks, but please be aware that the arrays I already have are of type `System.Array`. Thanks!

Comment: yep. please provide an answer, and then i will try (and delete the comments here). thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above you'll need a PowerShell [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6). By the way array in PowerShell are defined via `@()`, see [about_arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6) for further information.

```
$headings = @('h1', 'h2')
$values = @(3, 4)

$combined = @{ }

   if ($headings.Count -eq $values.Count) {
      for ($i = 0; $i -lt $headings.Count; $i++) {
         $combined[$headings[$i]] = $values[$i]
      }
}
else {
   Write-Error "Lengths of arrays are not the same"
}

$combined
```

Dumping the content of `combined` returns:

```
$combined

Name                           Value
----                           -----
h2                             4
h1                             3
```

Comment: He he .. I wanted him to figure out the `$combined` like you have defined, in my answer , that's why quoted it. Anyways, this is what I have meant actually. :) Also, I would like you to validate the length of the array so that headers are corresponding to the values.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
$hash = [ordered]@{ h1 = 3; h2 = 4}
$hash["h1"] # -- Will give you 3

## Next Approach
$headings = @('h1', 'h2') #array
$values = @(3, 4) #array

If($headings.Length -match $values.Length) 
{
    For($i=0;$i -lt $headings.Length; $i++) 
    {
      #Formulate your Hashtable here like the above and then you would be able to pick it up
      #something like this in hashtable variable $headings[$i] = $values[$i]
    }

}
```

PS: I am just giving you the logical headstart and helping you with the hashtable part. Code is upto you.